# Is there a way to check which S3 bucket is costing me the most for outgoing data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 50+ S3 buckets in my company AWS account. About 40% of my total monthly bill is for outgoing data transfer. Is there a way to get information on how much data is going out from which S3 bucket? (note: I am not looking for how much data the buckets have in storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Add a common tag to each bucket.
2. Activate the tag as a cost allocation tag.
3. Use the AWS Cost Explorer to create a cost report for the tag.
4. Wait a couple of days for AWS to catch up

Source: [How do I find the cost of my Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-find-bucket-cost/)

Comment: This works - but one has to be patient. After tagging the buckets, it takes a day or two for the tags to be available as filters on cost explorer. And it takes a few more days before the cost starts showing against those tags (for me, I added the tags in Dec and started seeing data from Jan 1st).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go over all the buckets and tag them with their name, you get it out of the box from amazon as the "Resource ID" (which is the bucket name). If you enabled resources in the Cost explorer or you're using the CUR file, just filter the product to "AmazonS3", aggregate by resource ID, and check the sum of your unBlendedCosts.

Good luck!